# Password should contain at least one number and one character

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I need to check whether my password contains one number and one character.

Input form

```
<input class="form-control" data-validate="required,minlength[8],alphaNumeric" id="password"  name="password" placeholder="password" type="text">
```

Below is my jQuery validate method.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphaNumeric", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);
}, "password must contain atleast one number and one character");
```

The problem is, the above regexp is not validating for the criteria where `password` should contain at least one number and one character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead regex like this to make sure it matches an input with at least 1 digit and 1 alphabet:

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[0-9a-z]+$/i
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?=\D*\d)((?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[0-9a-z]+$/: Unterminated group

Comment: Sorry had a typo, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/

If it works plz vote.